# How much current can a CD4013B drive?

Tags: flipflop

I'm attempting to make an EEPROM burning circuit using an Arduino Uno. Due to the lack of pins on the Uno, I opted to use shift registers for the address and data pins of this EEPROM. Aside from my current issue, everything will be powered from the 5v pin.

Before I ask my question, I'd like to clarify that I am an electronics beginner. Sure, I could have purchased an EPROM burner for ~$100 USD for this chip, but I'm a very DIY kind of guy and I only have a couple of these to burn, so the price doesn't seem to justify the cost.

The issue I'm examining now, before plugging in my circuit is I can't seem to find the maximum current allowed through a Q pin on this dual flip flop ([CD4013B](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/schs023)). I want to ensure I won't release the magic smoke from this IC by simply plugging it in. The purpose of this flip flop (as of now) is to toggle between read and write states for the EEPROM. As such, I've wired the VCC pins of an [SN74HC595](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scls041) and [SN74HC165](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scls116) to Q and !Q (unsure how to notate that here on SE) such that if one is on the other is off, and vice versa.

The CD4013B is running at only 5V, that's power and all inputs.

Here is what I think I know, and please correct me if I'm wrong! 
(I mean, I bought extras just in case, but still...)

- The SN74HC595 should not draw (or be loaded) over 35mA, or more likely 30 for a safety margin.
- The SN74HC165 should not draw (or be loaded) over 25mA / 20 or so for safety.

Now, being as these are both being used as for EEPROM data pins, I can imagine that the actual power draw will be significantly less than those maximums (though by how much I am really unsure).

Looking at the CD4013B datasheet, I can't seem to find any information regarding how much current this chip can handle.

Also, while I'm here talking about this specific IC, I'm finding the datasheet somewhat confusing.

- The output high current is always listed as a negative amperage... I didn't even realize this was possible. Is it due to the transistor logic of this particular device that current flows (I would assume) backwards?
- I also find it strange that the pins on this device are Vdd and Vss rather than Vcc and ground. Anybody care to explain why this is?

Comment: Figures 1 and 3 show the typical current @5V as 5mA with the output shorted to ground/vdd.

Comment: The CD4013B at 5 volts can sink about 0.5 mA and source about 1.5 mA. The CD series was designed in the 70's for battery operated devices, long before LED's and CMOS were on the market.

Comment: The Vdd and Vss are Drain and Source supplies.  Vcc and Vee used for bipolar parts are Collector and Emitter supplies.

Comment: The flip flop I'm using will be used in an old Commodore eventually, but I was hoping to dual-purpose it a bit.

Comment: CMOS dual FET are matched and RdsOn is inverse to Vgs=Vdd but you may compute RdsOn=Vol/Iol from datasheet @Vdd

Comment: As a general rule, you cannot blow up CD or 74HC series CMOS by shorting its outputs to gnd or +5. You can however blow it up by reversing the (high current) power supply or applying to much voltage. So an idiot diode e.g. a 6V2, 1W Zener across the supply rail is always a good idea while experimenting.

Comment: CD4013’s have a source R of >300 ohms , 74HC13’s are around 50-75 ohms and 3.3V logic is around 25 ohms

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "Electrical Charateristics (Static) table on Page 6 - that shows a typical source or sink current of 1 mA, with a 5 volt supply.

You would be better with a 74HC74 (or something else in the 74xC family), which gives +/- 8 mA.

Comment: I assume that I would probably be OK wiring up the outputs to an 2N2222 NPN transistor to do the actual power switching then... I'll have to look up the datasheet on that one again. Thanks for the info!